# Is there any way to configure struts.xml to send only non - null values to UI

Tags: struts2

I am looking at way to optimize my application. We are currently using struts2 framework. Is there any way to configure struts.xml to send only non - null values to UI ?

Comment: He/She doesn't want to check for null values in the JSP :)

Comment: Well, Andrea its partially true! There is little more to it. We have Single (Legacy services, not in scope to change) Pojos rendering to multiple services. Now depending on the service few values of the Pojo are populated. But we are sending (Sometime 50+ properties) to JSP with actual value in only one or two property. There are checks in UI in place to fetch the appropriate value, unfortunately maintainability is concern. Also, in the UI we have skim through this large objects to look for the right value. So I wondering if there was a way to send  only the properties that have value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No. What's exposed on the view layer has nothing to do with S2 configuration.

Also, since you're "sending" a POJO, "not sending" something means you don't actually want to "send" the same POJO. A POJO is just that: an instance of a Java class, and you cannot arbitrarily remove properties.

If you were sending, say, a hash, you could implement a result type that removed hash keys with null values in a pre-result listener. The bottom line is that your view layer would still need to know what it was supposed to have available to it.

You shouldn't have to "skim through" either a POJO or a hash to "look for the right value", your view layer should know what it's supposed to be displaying. If you have a view layer that's trying to adapt to what's present then this is solely a view-layer concern, even a decorator wouldn't help. You'd still need a helper/tag/etc. that wouldn't display its content if its associated value was null.